# What is the maximum memory a Google App Engine app may consume?

Tags: google-app-engine, gae-quotas

What is the maximum amount of *local* memory (*not* Memcache) each instance of a Google App engine app is allowed to consume?

I couldn't find any information on the [GAE quotas  page](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/quotas.html).

Comment: Nick Johnson mentions something about having a limit on the instance memory, on this post: http://blog.notdot.net/2010/11/Storage-options-on-App-Engine
But not the ammount. :(

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The maximum memory limit for an App Engine instance [depends on the instance class](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard#instance_classes) that you choose.  The default limit is 128 MB.  The following classes are currently available:

- F1 and B1 - 128 MB
- F2 and B2 - 256 MB
- F4 and B4 - 512 MB
- F4_1G, B4_1G - 1024 MB

Edit: Second generation instances have [double the memory](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/application-development/app-engine-second-generation-runtimes-now-get-double-the-memory-plus-go-112-and-php-73-now-generally-available):

- F1 and B1 - 256 MB
- F2 and B2 - 512 MB
- F4 and B4 - 1024 MB
- F4_HIGHMEM and B4_HIGHMEM - 2048 MB
- B8 - 2048 MB

Comment: @user2284570 the link you provided is for Compute Engine.  App Engine has different memory limits

Comment: Anyway, the link in your answer does no longer contains that information. You must update it.

Comment: the link is deprecated

Answer (score 5):

The maximum amount of local memory is not documented.

***speculation***:
I believe they have not imposed any hard limits because it may depend on your application traffic/load/activity and by other GAE applications.

There's an open issue [**MemoryError undocumented/hard to predict**](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=1646) that you might want to star.

**EDIT:**
Reading the new Backends documentation [here](http://code.google.com/intl/it/appengine/docs/python/backends/overview.html) it seems capped to **128MB**