# Is 'Memory' and 'Bandwidth' same? What does it mean in Google App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, gcloud, cloud-hosting

I actually Don't understand what's the difference between **RAM, MEMORY and BANDWIDTH** here...
I Couldn't find any information about this in Google Cloud Docs.

Is Bandwidth and Memory same thing??

Comment: Memory is RAM. Memory bandwidth is the rate at which data can be read from or stored into RAM by a processor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Memory and Bandwidth are not the same things on GAE. Bandwidth is how much data will be processed by your application. You can get more information on bandwidth on this [Quotas](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/quotas?csw=1#Requests) page.

Instance Memory is the cache data stored locally by GAE. You can get more information on limits of Memory on GAE on this other post: [What is the maximum memory a Google App Engine app may consume?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4232691/what-is-the-maximum-memory-a-google-app-engine-app-may-consume).

RAM would be how much memory RAM you want to have for your application run. This is configured in the [app.yaml](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/go/reference/app-yaml) file.

Let me know if the information helped you!